# cannot get count of items for ng-repeat pagination

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement pagination in my `ng-repeat` template, and I am using the code that I found in [How to do paging in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs), namely, this: http://jsfiddle.net/dalcib/J3fjc/.

my code is almost the same as that in this jsfiddle example, except for instead of using hard coded values, I use an injected service that fetches data from a url that returns json.

the problem that I am having is that the length of the collection is always zero in the jsfiddle code, and I do not know why because I am a newbie. here is the relevant code:

```
...
collection = scope.$eval(rhs),
count = collection.length;
```

`count` is always zero. It looks like the code is executed before the response from the service is received.

can anyone help?

Comment: If you are fetching asynchronous data, then you need to put functionality in a callback or you could use the `$watch` method and run the necessary code when you get the data. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497590/how-do-you-handle-asynchronous-data-in-directives-for-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use $eval().
$eval is to take a string and get the object with this name.
What you can do is only to associate to a scope variable your json object that you get in the Service or in the Resource. 
In ng-repeat you use his scope variable .

```
function gridCtrl($scope, sameResource) {
      sameResource.query( function (todos) {
             $scope.todos = todos;
       }
}
```

In the view

```
<div ng-repeat="todo in todos"> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're looking for $index.

for example:

```
<html ng-app>
  <head></head>
  <body ng-init="poops = ['fat tony','the turdis','hershey squirts']">
    <div ng-repeat="poo in poops">{{ poo + "/" + $index}}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

outputs:

```
fat tony/0
the turdis/1
hershey squirts/2
```