# Wait for data in controller before link function is run in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I ensure that data from a controller has been loaded in a directive before the link function is run?

Using psuedo-code, I could have:

```
<my-map id="map-canvas" class="map-canvas"></my-map>
```

for my html.

In my directive I might have something like this:

```
app.directive('myMap', [function() {



return{
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<div></div>',
    replace: true,
    controller: function ($scope, PathService) {

        $scope.paths = [];

        PathService.getPaths().then(function(data){
            $scope.paths = data;

        });

    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        console.log($scope.paths.length);

    }

}


}]);
```

The above won't work because console.log($scope.paths.length); will get called before the service has returned any data.

I know I can call the service from the link function but would like to know if there is a way to "wait" for the service call before firing the link function.

Comment: maybe you can use an event in your service. (i do the same for some  visual access restrictions) just use `$scope.$on("service-event", ...` in your directive and in your service `$rootScope.$broadcast("service-event", payload);`

Comment: Have a `scope.$watch('paths'` in the link function to see when the that variable gets data.

Comment: Will try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497590/how-do-you-handle-asynchronous-data-in-directives-for-angularjs

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use `ng-if` since the element and directive would be rendered only when the `ng-if` is resolved as true

```
<my-map id="map-canvas" class="map-canvas" ng-if="dataHasLoaded"></my-map>

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, service){
  $scope.dataHasLoaded = false;

  service.loadData().then(
    function (data) {
      //doSomethingAmazing
      $scope.dataHasLoaded = true
    }
  )
})
```

or use promises

```
return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  template: '<div></div>',
  replace: true,
  controller: function ($scope, PathService) {
    $scope.paths = [];
    $scope.servicePromise = PathService.getPaths()
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.servicePromise.then(function (data) {
      scope.paths = data;
      console.log(scope.paths)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The directive and controller would not be created if used with falsy `ng-if` but if the data you are loading is used by the directive and not required in controller it would make sense to use it `link`/`controller` of the directive

Comment: This is not working. The ng-if statement is removing the my-map tag from the dom and the controller is never firing.

Comment: I tried using a controller that was not based in the directive and it still is not working. This must be a solution for <1.2.0.

Comment: James as I said if you use ng-if then directive and controller will not be created, but if you are using the data only in this directive you can omit `ng-if` and load data inside directive's controller

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll mark it as correct as it is close enough to what I need. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that ng-if runs on each scope digest

Answer (score 1):

```js
app.directive('MyDirective', function() {
    return {
        controller: function() {
            this.$postLink = function() {
            // here will run after the link function,
            // and also after the binding came in
            };
        },
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    };
});
```

check out the angular 1.5 [Components have a well-defined lifecycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture) and it works on directives to