# How to call Angularjs directive after the return of another function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angularjs-directive

I have on my website a code similar to the following:

```
<div ng-click=someFunction() my-directive>...</div>
<div ng-show=showMe>...</div>
```

The function someFunction() looks as follows:

```
function onSuccess() {
    // do something
    console.log("in response")
}
function someFunction() {
    $http( 
        {
         ...
         }).then(onSuccess);

}
```

The directive my-directive is created as follows:

```
app.directive(myDirective, function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, $elm) {
                $elm.on('click', function() {
                    console.log("in directive");
                    //do something
                });
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that I need the directive to fire only after onSuccess had finished what it loaded and not before (i.e., I want to see in the console "in response" before "in directive" and right now I see "in directive" first)

It looks like something doable but I can't find how...
Any help/ideas will be appreciated!

EDIT:
I just saw this answer: [Wait for data in controller before link function is run in AngularJS directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485990/wait-for-data-in-controller-before-link-function-is-run-in-angularjs-directive) It is not what I'm looking for as the function someFunction is independent of the directive and I want it to stay as independent as possible (the function is placed in the controller of the app and I don't want to manipulate the view directly from there).

EDIT 2:
I am aware of the possibility to use timeout but I'd rather use a more general solution. With timeout I'll have to guess how long to wait and I don't want to rely on that.

EDIT 3:
I edited the function someFunction to a more specific one. I can't change the structure of someFunction and I don't want to do the directive's work in onSuccess.

thanks again!

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27486190/3567063) might be what you're looking for. Please, ignore this comment.

Comment: @alex_andrea I would have suggested the same, but I don't think it will work with attribute directives and a click listener on the same object. You can only add or remove an element with `ng-if` and not an attribute of an element.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 i've never thought of that. Thanks for pointing out.:)

Comment: thanks for your comments but as @ssc-hrep3 pointed the mentioned answer won't help here. thanks :-)

Comment: In your scenario you have response which linked to the DOM element click event so we can not use ng-if. so go for $timeout function.

Comment: One way is to link the controller and the directive with a scope variable (`<a my-directive="isClicked" />`). You set the variable to true, when the click listener is fired and the variable is passed to the directive. But also in this case you need an interval in the directive which checks if there is a change to this variable... I hope there is some better solution :)

Comment: Before the help just going to state that probably you should rethink how you are components communicate and the priorities between the controllers and directives. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/wLiRE0J1DPA1qJxynqwR?p=preview) you are going to find a way of the controller call a code given by the directive, through sharing a callback in the scope. Note: the $timeout there is only to simulate a http request, it is to be replaced with the $http request that you need.

Comment: Other way to achieve your desired behaviour is to on success of the http request change a variable on the scope and make an ng-watch on the directive to that scope variable, example [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/kHxCYdEe1ScYjEtZSTSA?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If you add several event listeners to the same element, they are executed in the order of the `addEventListener()` calls. For example

```
e.addEventListener('click', function(){ console.log('Click 1'); });
e.addEventListener('click', function(){ console.log('Click 2'); });
```

would first show "Click 1" then "Click 2". That doesn't seem to be the case for Angular, because you say that the directive fires first.

If you can modify the directive, I would simply wait for 100 ms or so.

```
link: function(scope, $elm) {
    $elm.on('click', function() {
        $timeout(function(){
            console.log("in directive");
                //do something
            });
        }, 100);
    }
```

to give the controller time to do its things.

Comment: hi, timeout will probably do the job but I am looking for a more general solution (and as you wrote, the eventlisteners aren't relevant here). thanks  anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you, to use another approch. Don't use ng-click but pass your function into your directive

```
app.directive(myDirective, function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function(scope, $elm, iattrs) {
            $elm.on('click', function() {
                scope.$eval(iattrs.myDirective)
                .then(function(response) {
                   console.log("in directive");
                   //do something
                });
            });
       }
   }
});
```

Please see this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/PaV6cCn0NmpBIVaJGAEL?p=preview

It supposed the function return a promise

Comment: hi, thanks. The problem is that the function someFunction calls a http and I want the directive to be called after its callback finished running.

Comment: I don't understand. $http return a promise you can return it instead of my promise example. And you can execute directive code after $http send response. 
When you said 'directive to be called after its callback finished', you want angular call link function after ?

Comment: I simply can't do that. My code works differently and I can't return the promise.

Comment: OK so write your complet someFunction()

Comment: edited the question. The complete implementation is irrelevant as I don't want to change its structure as other elements are dependent on it